# How to create a water like animation in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

Cane any body tell me how to create a water like animation when switching from one Activity to another Activity.If anybody have a sample xml file can you share with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are talking about?  "Water like" animation is pretty vague.

Comment: Hi, do you got that water like animation in android? I need that , if you got, share me some help. Thanks